# Making new variables for every group of observation in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have 11 variables in my dataframe. The first is unique identifier of observation (a plane). The second one is a number from 1 to 21 representing flight of a given plane. The rest of the variables are time, velocity, distance, etc.

What I want to do is make new variables for every group (number) of flight e.g. `time_1`, `time_2`,..., `velocity_1`, `velocity_2`, etc. and consequently, reduce the number of observations (the repeating ones).

I don't really have idea how to start. I was thinking about a mutate function like:

```
mutate(df, time_1 = ifelse(n_flight == 1, time, NA))
```

But that would be a lot of typing and a new problem may appear, perhaps.

Comment: Reproducible example. Please.

Comment: This seems very SQL-like. Perhaps you want to filter yourdataframe by column or call unique() or distinct() over your dataframe to remove repeated rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to convert long to wide data for each variable. You can `lapply` over these with `tidyr::spread` in that case. Suppose the data looks like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)), 
  n_flight = rep(seq(3), 2),
  time = seq(19, 24), 
  velocity = rev(seq(65, 60))
)
```

Then the following will generate your outcome of interest, as long as you get rid of the extra ID variables.

```
lapply(
  setdiff(names(df), c("ID", "n_flight")), function(x) {
    df %>% 
      select(ID, n_flight, !!x) %>%
      tidyr::spread(., key = "n_flight", value = x) %>%
      setNames(paste(x, names(.), sep = "_"))
  }
) %>%
  bind_cols()
```

Let me know if this wasn't what you were going for.

Comment: Thank you! This is excatly what i was looking for. sorry for the delayed response :)